# replace velues in column matching based on 2 columns

Tags: awk

I have file f1 which looks like this: (has 1651 lines)

```
fam0110 G110 0 0 0 1 T G
fam6106 G6106 0 0 0 2 T T
fam1000 G1000 0 0 0 2 T T
...
```

and I have file f2 which looks like (has 1651 lines)

```
fam1000 G1000 1 1
fam6106 G6106 1 1
fam0110 G110 2 2
...
```

I would like to replace the 6th column in f1 so that it matches the 3rd column of f2 os that they match by the 1st and 2nd column

the output would look like this:

```
fam0110 G110 0 0 0 2 T G
fam6106 G6106 0 0 0 1 T T
fam1000 G1000 0 0 0 1 T T
```

I tried to do it with:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$6=a[FNR]}1' pheno_laser2 chr9.plink.ped > chr9.new.ped
```

but this doesn't work because the lines are not sorted in the same way so I need matching by the values in the 1st and 2nd column in the both files.

Please advise
my the this doesn't work because

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use only the first two fields into the hash, as you want to match only for them, not for the line number or anything else.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1, $2]=$3;next} {$6=a[$1, $2]}1' file2 file1
```

Testing with your examples:

```
fam0110 G110 0 0 0 2 T G
fam6106 G6106 0 0 0 1 T T
fam1000 G1000 0 0 0 1 T T
```

Note that it would print empty field for any not matching lines, I assume this is ok.